# How to overcome situations like mostly coded less content website?

Tags: seo, google, content

**Background about site** : I have a website which is similar to question and answer site like StackOverFlow, but **NOT** user generated content and **only** one answer. Me and a few friend create the pages / posts. And this site is for **programmers**.

Example Page of my website:

> **How to Add your WordPress custom post types to your sites main RSS feed by
>   default?**
>
> Registering a custom post type does not mean it gets added to the main
>   RSS feed automatically in WordPress.You need to use [request filter](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/request) to add custom
>   post types to main RSS feed.
>
> ```
> // Add 'books' custom post types on main RSS feed
> function add_book_post_types_to_rss($qv) {
>     if (isset($qv['feed']) && !isset($qv['post_type']))
>         $qv['post_type'] = array('post', 'books', );
>     return $qv;
> }
> add_filter('request', 'add_book_post_types_to_rss');
> ```

Currently we have 75+ posts and we hope to add 500+ pages within two years. Almost all pages are very similar to above page.

**The problem we have faced**

We targeting mostly SEO traffic for this site. But we have very less organic traffic even our website is one year old.

We thought following reason is the main reason for it.

- Lack of content in **single page / post** : As you already see this
  page has about just 50 words and **we don't like adding some garbage
  words to just increase word count**. We are focusing on adding more
  pages/ posts and make big resources collection about WordPress, PHP,
  JavaScript, etc.

Is there any solution for overcome this problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the best ways to increase a site's position in Google?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2/what-are-the-best-ways-to-increase-a-sites-position-in-google)

Comment: I will think about my keywords position not about traffic. If only few people search query is matched with my page, then how I can get more traffic on it?. So add your site into search console and look into [search analytics reports](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6155685?hl=en). The less content also rank very well, SO is example of that.

Comment: @closetnoc I think this is not a duplicate question for it because I have specify what is the problem in my website. I am finding a solution for that specific problem. And this is difference than https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/107356/how-to-overcome-the-situation-of-having-lack-of-content-and-not-updating-regular also because I am asking about 'Lack of content in single page / post'.............

Comment: @Goyllo We have already research about it and problem is not that.... I mean there are good search queries, but our site in 2-10 pages most time..........

Comment: It seems that you are answering your own question.  "lack of content".  If that is the case, the answer is "more content" and not just garbage.  Create meaningful content.

Comment: @Steve Our readers are programmers and they know the basics. So most of the time no need to explain more words to explain the code.... And we have put comments with the code.... So easily they can understand the code.... Because of that it is really hard to add more content which is meaningful....

Comment: While shorter content can perform very well in Google, this content only performs well when it can answer questions. This is because the answer engine picks up on content that can answer questions from the knowledge graph. The format of your content, or at the example you provided, does not allow for inclusion into the knowledge graph. You will need to study this. Your content, less code, is not enough. Remember code does not make for good searchable content and often fails. So what is left when the code is removed? Not much. This is where you answer questions. Work on that.

Comment: @DonkeyKing As others have indicated, it appears that you've already identified the solution to your problem, which is to improve your content. Unfortunately we cannot tell you how to do that specifically. The question marked as a duplicate may offers some other ideas. In the future, please do not edit your question with feedback to the community unless you're adding new information - questions are not meant to be an open dialog, that's what comments are for.

Comment: @dan Thanks...  It asked something like please edit your question if you feel like this is not a duplicate question................................ That's why I edit the question to telling how deffer my question is for others.

Comment: @DonkeyKing Sure, I understand. That means to edit the question so that it's significantly _different_  than the one marked as a duplicate (i.e.., not to point out the differences inside the question). In this case, the question marked as a duplicate is a very broad questions that's used as a "catch-all" question for those that we cannot answer specifically, so that's not really applicable in your case. Comments are just fine for that, and Meta can be used for extended discussions regarding community policies and decisions.